# ref prop on textarea; "No overload matches this call'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am following the documentation to set a ref using the `useRef` hook, so that I can clear an input field programmatically. But adding `ref` as a prop to a textarea is causing `no overload matches this call` to lint. The same error provents compilation during `npm run dev`:

```
// inside a function component
 const textAreaRef = React.useRef('');

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
          <LargeTextArea
            ref={textAreaRef} // no overload matches this call
            rows={8}
            onChange={(e: any) => setRawInputString(e.target.value) }
            onKeyDown={({ ctrlKey, key }: any) => {
              if(ctrlKey && key === "Enter") {
                textAreaRef.current.value = '';
              }
            }}
          />

// outside the main component definition
const LargeTextArea = styled.textarea`...removed`
```

Does anyone see what the issue is that is causing the ref prop not to be recognized?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your ref to look like this

`const textAreaRef = React.useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>(null)`

Before changing the value of your ref first wrap it in an if statement to check if ref.current exists and then do your value change.

```
if(textAreaRef.current) {
  textAreaRef.current.value = ''
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I notice I must change the initial state to `null` to avoid the same error. But doing so then causes a related lint error: `textAreaRef.current.value = '';   // object is possibly null`

Comment: Thank you, I am accepting this answer but there is a typo. Please change `ref` to `textAreaRef`. Thanks again

Comment: Ah! Fixed it. Good luck!